# Why List<Long>.get(0) returns a double?

Tags: java, android

I got an error when began to iterate in a list. My list's type is `Long`. But when it started to iterate, it shows the error that could not convert `double` to `long`!

```
List<Long> orderNos = settingRepository.getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit();
for (long orderNo : orderNos) {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public List<Long> getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit() {
    String orders = settingPref.getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit();
    return StringHelper.deserialize(orders);
}

public static < T > T deserialize(String obj){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type token = new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(obj, token);
}
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Long

What is the problem here? If my values are double then it should throw the exception in the first line where it fills the `List<long>`, not in the second one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does `settingRepository.getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit()` return a raw `List`?

Comment: @Eran Its signature is: List<Long> getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit(). Actually, I serialize and deserialize some long number in SharedPref and settingRepository reads pref and convert it to List<Long>

Comment: your code compiles and runs without problems if the List is indeed filled with Long values

Comment: Can you show the code that creates and populates the List returned by `getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit()`?

Comment: @Eran I put them

Comment: It seems like your JSON contains double values. Why do you think they are longs in the first place?

Comment: Because I put there a long value of OrderNumber. And my question is that why should a long type accept double and if it casts it why it shows error when retrieving it?

Comment: did you tried using `for (Long orderNo : orderNos) {` instead of `long`

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if `settingRepository.getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit()` is doing something naughty - (ab)using raw types.

I recreated a similar situation here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> list = getLongList();
    for (Long l : list) {
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}

public static List<Long> getLongList() {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    l.add(1.2);
    return l;
}
```

My `getLongList` method is declared to return a `List<Long>`, but what I am actually doing in there is creating a raw `List`, putting a `Double` in it, and returning it.

Because I am using raw types, the compiler stops checking for type safety, allowing me to return a `List` containing a `Double` when I am supposed to return a `List<Long>`.

The list gets returned to the caller `main`, and note that since generics is only checked in compile time, the runtime doesn't know that something wrong has happened at this line:

```
List<Long> list = getLongList();
```

The runtime only knows that something wrong has happened when you try to get the items out of the list and say that they are `Long`s, which they are not.

So you should probably have a look inside `settingRepository.getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit()`. If this method is written by you, you should probably edit it to not use raw types, then a compiler error will probably appear, and that will lead you to fix the problem.

Comment: Then why `l.add(1.2);` should accept this value if it's a `long` type? And if it casts it to long, then why should show error while iterating when values are casted?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos `l` is not a `List<Long>`. `l.add()` could accept anything because `l` is a raw type `List`. The only casting that happens is when you loop through the list. Remember that generics don't exist at runtime. But it seems like using raw types is not the cause your specific problem here. Your JSON seems to contain doubles, yet you still try to make them longs. Why?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos The runtime doesn't know that you are using `Long`s in the line `List<Long> orderNos = settingRepository.getUnchangedOrdersNoInCardindeForEdit();` because at runtime, all generics are erased. It is when you start getting the items out of the list that you start saying to the runtime, "I want this to be a `Long`, ok?" and the runtime says "no", because it's actually a double.

Comment: But in line 1 there's no error at runtime. Suppose my value is a double, then why List<Long> accept double members. This is what makes it confusing me

Comment: At runtime, `List<Long>` and `List<Double>` _are the same thing_ - `List`. The `<>` part will be "deleted" at runtime. `List` can store anything, including `Double`. The `<Long>` is just you telling the _compiler_ "Please make sure that I only put `Long`s in here". But there are some things that the compiler can't make sure (like the fact that your JSON contains long values). That can only be determined as runtime. At runtime, the `<Long>` is gone, so it doesn't check the type. It only checks the type when you extract the values from the list (i.e. in the for loop). @SiamakFerdos